# Change archive results based on GET request

Tags: posts, wp-query

I'm building a filter system, hoping to change the page's contents by a GET request. I've got 3 different kind of taxonomies.

At the moment, if I add the following to the URL: `?season_key=sp17`, it filters the archive so **only posts tagged with the season sp17 are shown**.

However, I'd like to make the query more complex, by including another taxonomy type: `?season_key=sp17&account_key=dtc`.

This is attempting to search for **any** **seasons with sp17**, or **accounts with dtc**.

However, it returns nothing.

Is there a way to combine GET requests for custom taxonomies, and is there any documentation for the more complex cases? Not quite sure what to search for.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to make this work.
What you can do for example, target a page and in the theme for this page or better say the template go and read the GET and make the filtering there.

Another approach and what I personally do is create a page and then start playing with the ([add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)) This way I can have clean urls and filter the data in a backend function.

Both ways can give you the flexibility to add more filtering options without big changes.